# Why isn't scheduled chkdsk running on reboot?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I have a laptop with reported NTFS errors in the System log (visible in the Event Viewer). My first step was to schedule chkdsk and have the user let it run when they got home. This didn't work, so then I attempted to schedule and run it myself. I ran the vendor-supplied diagnostics CD and it finds no problem with the disk, so I really need a successful chkdsk run before I proceed further and see if errors crop up again.

Environment: Windows 7 Professional with SP1 64-bit.

UAC is enabled, and my actions are being performed from an elevated command prompt. I've tried:

```
chkdsk C: /F /R
```

and

```
chkdsk C: /F
```

Both options prompt me to schedule it on restart, and I press Y. I reboot, and it goes straight to a login screen. No chkdsk. Powering off, then turning back on also does not work. (I'm only trying one option at a time).

**What are the possible reasons chkdsk isn't running when I schedule it?**

Comment: I'm not sure why this got moved. It should be highly relevant to desktop support...

Answer (score 2):

[NTFS Self healing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2008/10/29/self-healing-ntfs.aspx) might be turned on (it is by default) so it didn't see a need to run chkdsk.

Comment: +1 as this sounds promising. I'll try checking the setting tomorrow, but it blindly not running when scheduled seems like a dumb idea to me. Tomorrow I'll try verifying this setting and manually setting the dirty flag to see if that triggers it. Since the event viewer is saying to run chkdsk, and the only way to run it on primary OS drive is to schedule it on reboot or boot with other media...

Comment: It still bugs me that Windows is SAYING chkdsk needs to be run...if NTFS self healing prevented the problem, then chkdsk would not need to run in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this unexplained behavior was to create a Windows System Repair disc, and boot to that and then run chkdsk. Any way to get the disk unmounted would work, this was just the one I chose. When I ran it, it found and repaired errors as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a laptop with reported NTFS errors in the registry.

The registry is just a file on the hard drive. The hard drive is formatted with the NTFS file system. The registry cannot have file-system errors in it. Perhaps the error is the registry and not the file system, which is why chkdsk doesn't run as there is no reason to check the disk for errors.

Comment: Indeed - I meant to say event viewer...aka the system log, viewed in event viewer